# Directly use of NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I find I usually directly use a NSString like:

```
 self.text = @"word";
 label.text = @"word";
 function(@"word");
```

I think it is a wrong way to directly use NSString, because the @"word" will have a retainCount of 2 after it has been used. Is that right?

What is exactly the retainCount of @"" ? Is it an autorelease object or has a retain of 1?

What`s more, I encountered some memory leak as the pic shown below:

[image]

I suspect it is related to the direct use of the NSString.

Comment: An `@"literal"` string should generally be treated AS IF it were autoreleased.  It is, however, a "constant" that exists for the life of the executing program ("infinite" retain count, as stated below), so one can play a little fast and loose with it.

Comment: (I suspect your leak is not directly related to the use of string literals.)

Comment: retainCount is useless. Don't call it.  Your leak is unrelated.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially, the retain count of NSString literals is infinite. The memory for these objects is reserved by the compiler at compile time and never gets released for the duration that your app is running, no matter how often you try to retain or release them.

This is another good example why it is wrong to care about retain counts. You should only care about the golden memory management rules: if you take ownership of an object (with `alloc`, `new`, `copy` or `retain`), you have to release or autorelease it later. Otherwise, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [String programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-CJBCJHHI)

> The simplest way to create a string object in source code is to use the Objective-C @"..." construct:
>
> NSString *temp = @"/tmp/scratch";
>
> Note that, when creating a string constant in this fashion, you should avoid using anything but 7-bit ASCII characters. Such an object is created at compile time and exists throughout your program’s execution. The compiler makes such object constants unique on a per-module basis, and they’re never deallocated, though you can retain and release them as you do any other object.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a good thing to declare an autoreleased NSString by using directly @"". But NSString are retained in a particular way and it's not really possible to know what's being done at runtime. You may have weird retain count sometimes. Don't bother about your leak of 48 Bytes.... It's not related to your nsstring.

Comment: Actually using `@""` syntax you are not creating autoreleased string. And yes, the OP's memory leak is related to the string he created.

Comment: Okay then, lets us say we dont own the nsstring

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The memory leak is not related to the allocation. I recovered your original answer.

Answer (score 1):

> the @"word" will have a retainCount of 2 after it has been used. Is that right?

No.  This is a perfect illustration of why it is bad to think in terms of retain counts which are an internal implementation detail.  You can think of string literals as strings that are "owned" by the executable image so they will not go away.  You should treat them like any other Objective-C object.

If you do take a sneaky peek at the retain count of a string literal, you'll find it is set to some really big number (something like the maximum value for an `NSInteger`).  This is treated as a special value by `retain` and `release` that they don't change.

The memory for string literals is allocated as part of the binary image at compile time.  It can never go away.  Your memory leak is not because of this.